# Splitting a point layer in equal parts in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I need to split a point layer in equal parts, let´s say I have 3252 and want to split in 15 equal groups of points (average is almost 217 points).
I am using QGIS 3.10 in Windows.

Comment: What have you tried?  East to west? North to south? Geographic clusters? Please [Edit] the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new field to the attribute table.

Use the Field Calculator to update the new field with this expression:

```
@row_number % 15
```

This will have the same effect as counting the points off in groups of 15 - each point will get a value between 0 and 14.

Use the `split vector layer` to split your points based on this field. Now you have 15 separate layers with an equal number of points in each layer.

For a different number of groups, substitute the desired number of groups for `15` in the field calculator expression.